# Inline Code Highlighting?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, syntax-highlighting

When you use `inline code`, it isn't highlighted.

I even tried surrounding it with `<code>` tags, but it still doesn't work.

Here's [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4998655/901641) where I noticed the bug.

The question is tagged with Python, and the snippet is a little bit of code that would be highlighted if it was done on its own line or between `<pre>` tags (but that throws it on its own line anyways)... it seems like a bug to me that because it's inline, it isn't highlighted.

Comment: I am not sure what you are seeing but [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/aSYCu.png) is what I see and it looks fine to me.

Comment: @NathanOliver - That's the same as what I see. It's incorrect. Put the same code in a code block and the strings will changed to brown (which makes it easier to tell the difference between the comma separating the arguments from the comma within a string.)

Comment: [This MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2737/code-coloring-for-inline-code-in-answers) seems to imply that inline code never gets syntax highlight.  Which makes sense since most of the time inline code isn't complex enough to need the highlight.  If it is complex, it should be a proper code section indented by 4 spaces on a new line.

Comment: Perhaps [the syntax highlighting instructions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/364344) should be updated if this is indeed by design.

Answer (score 7):

Syntax highlighting only works on code blocks not inline code.

This is very much by design.

Comment: Then I'd like to make this a feature request. This doesn't make sense as a design choice. I'd retag it myself but it gives me an error about touching moderator tags when I try that.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare *"This doesn't make sense as a design choice"* - could you expand on that?

Comment: @jonrsharpe - It's inconsistent. Why is some code treated to formatting if it's on its own line but not when it's in-line? There's no performance argument to be made - it's entirely client side, not something that concerns the server. If this is "by design", then the design itself has a bug that needs to be fixed.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare Syntax highlighting exists to make larger blocks of code easier to read and parse in your mind. Inline code is inherently meant for small snippets which do not suffer from such a problem, and thus syntax highlighting is simply not necessary.

Comment: @animuson `(',', ' ')` - short and simple, no need to go in its own block, and yet benefits from highlighting. When is highlighting ever not useful? Do you ever look at your code and think, "this is so simple, it'll benefit from if I turn off code highlighting."

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare "When is highlighting ever not useful" -> When it distracts from the content. For example, [NASA found that too many colours *increases* errors for air flight controllers](http://colorusage.arc.nasa.gov/guidelines_ov_design.php). Code and text isn't an air traffic controller UI, but I see no reason why the same principle shouldn't apply here. Inline code highlighting *on top* of highlighting it as code is too much...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker - Great link, thanks! Please see the final section, which says you should be consistent. This is precisely my point. Why do we sometimes highlight code but other times not highlight it? That's inconsistent.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare The context is different. In a a large code block, there is *only* code, so the context is code. But when I use inline, I am using it in the context of text, to disambiguate between text and code which can help reduce confusion. When you start adding colours to that, in the text, what you get is a paragraph of text with three, four, or more colours used throughout. This just distracts from the text and adds very little value to the inline code example.

Comment: Aside from that, there are also some technical/usability issues. If I say "run the `foo` function", then that may get highlighted as a variable or identifier (or maybe even an error) depending on the language, which is wrong. I now *need* to say "run the `foo()` function". There are probably more examples to be found. Plus, not all `inline block` convey code in the language the question is tagged with (especially in comments they're often used as quotes). And what if a question is tagged with [tag:python] and [tag:vim]? Do I now need to mark my inline `:example` as Vim ex commands not Python?

Comment: And last but not least: remember this will be applied to *all* posts written over the last eight years retroactively. Are you *sure* this won't cause really strange highlighting to be applied to some of those? ... The more I think about this, the more problems I see with doing this :-) I understand what you're trying to say, but this "small change" will have far more impact than you think :-)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker, all you have to do is run a conversion that puts <!-- language: lang-none --> before each inline block if there isn't already a language specification that applies to it. As controversial as it may be, I agree with ArtOfWarfare that inline code (especially with commas in strings as in his example!) would benefit from highlighting, and with my suggestion, shouldn't cause a detriment either.

Comment: @NH. Well, that will uglify a lot of Markdown? I also really don't want to be typing `<!-- ... -->` for every post I make just to prevent some strange colours from appearing.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker, in that case, you could just make it so if we explicitly want it, we could specify the language.

Comment: @jonrsharpe It would be useful in two ways. Firstly, tiny and obvious bits of code that could be done with syntax-highlighted inline code may have to be moved to blocks because non syntax highlighted code obfuscates its meaning. Second, sometimes syntax highlighting is crucial to conveying the meaning of the code. Just like body language (and other contextual communication) can be important when speaking.